# Are there more env variables appart from the ones I see when I type ENV?

Tags: java, r, environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion, rapidminer

I am trying to make the R extension for `RapidMiner` to work, and for that I have to follow some steps which include setting some enviromental variables to make sure RapidMiner is able to *see* where Java and R are.

Both environmental variables to be set are `R_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`

I have set up both variables and I am able to see them when I type `env` on my terminal, but when I run RapidMiner R is not working. On the logs I see the following:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
R_HOME is not set. Please set all required environment variables before running this program.
Unable to start R
Jul 15, 2013 3:05:25 PM com.rapidminer.tools.r.JRIRSession initializeEngine
SEVERE: Could not initialize R via JRI. Reason: Unable to initialize R
Jul 15, 2013 3:05:25 PM com.rapidminer.gui.r.RConsole <init>
SEVERE: Could not acquire connection to R: Could not initiate session with native R. Try using server. Reason: Could not initialize R via JRI. Reason: Unable to initialize R
```

So now I am wondering why RapidMiner is not able to read my environmental variables in the same way I do.

Is is possible that RM is reading the variables from a different location? Is there anyway I can make sure?

Any tip will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What is you R_HOME value? and your OS?

Comment: Hi, R_HOME=/usr/bin/R (this is what I see when I type whereis R) and my OS is Mountain Lion, I posted it as a tag but maybe I should have posted it in the description.

Comment: The environment variables that are set in your shell ( which is what is being displayed by Terminal.app) may not be visible to other applications. If RapidMiner has a `system` function you should use that to set the environment variables from inside a session.

Comment: Another (untested) option might be to save the variable to the bash profile file: http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/255324-problems-setting-path-variable-lion.html#post1317516

Comment: What if you set R_HOME like this `R_HOME=/usr/bin/R/R-version/`?

Comment: I tried with `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources` and setting the envs inside `bash_profile` but still RM argues about R_HOME not being set. Something odd I found out is that although `whereis R` answers `/usr/bin/R` when I go to `/user/bin/` I don't see `R` in there, but if I type `R` from terminal then `R` starts normally.

Comment: yes, that was a typo, I meant `/usr/bin/` sorry about that.

Comment: My MacOS setup which is fairly standard, does not have any R executables in usr/bin/. By default Finder.app will not show usr/bin/ but what happens in a terminal session if you type: `ls /usr/bin/R`

Comment: It looks like its a symlink because when I type `ls -l /usr/bin/` I get `/usr/bin/r -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R` I will try now with `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R` instead of `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/`

UPDATE: Unfortunately, the same error, RM is not able to locate R_HOME..even though R_HOME is there

Comment: I doubt that is the problem. The system should have been able to follow the symlink. I still think the problem is that you are not effectively exporting the environment variable in a form that can be found by RapidMiner.

Comment: But if the environment variable is there when I type env is there anything else I can do to make it more visible?